# Spring MVC into Vaadin application

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin

Recently we were developing web application based on Vaadin and Spring (Core). Now we are trying to make it better :) Our main problem is very slow generation of screens with big amount of data. (We used CustomLayout but it still not the thing we were looking)

I was thinking recently about integrating Spring MVC for only this few screens. And here goes my question "how can I do that"? Do you have any idea were should I start ? 
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185353/vaadin-and-spring-mvc-integration), but it is not what I was expected.

Do you guys have any idea how can I do this ?

thx 
Lukasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for this part of question "very slow generation of screens with big amount of data", you can try to use [fastlayouts Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/fastlayouts), it should improve component rendering time and [lazy query container Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/lazy-query-container) with allow you to "lazy" load item into, for example, table or some where you need.

"integrating Spring MVC for only this few screens" can you explain this part, because as I understand you want to integrate Spring MVC only for some "view", it mean Spring should be initialize only in case if this "views" were selected, am I right?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers.

So first of all -> our current solution - we use tables. Yeah... more than one in a view (problems with width, and some others "must have").

Comment: As for "integrating Spring MVC for only this few screens" -> yeas if user enters viewA I want to display this view using spring MVC only. How ever... I believe that our table method will work for now :) 

Sorry for double posts (I hit enter too many times...)